# Como obtener datos Json de varias urls para renderizar una sola DataTable

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, json, datatables

Tengo dos URLs que sirven datos de objetos en formato `JSON`, ambos formatos tiene la misma estructura, excepto por el tipo de equipo:

**Primera URL:** *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/equipos/?rack=1*

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tipo_equipo": "EquipoA", ///Esto es diferente al otro
    "nomenclatura": "0501",
    "etiqueta": "Sin Eqtiqueta",
    "rack": "1"
}
```

**Segunda URL:** *http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sws/?rack=1*

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tipo_sw": "ADCDi-R2CU1", ///esto es diferente al de arriba
    "nomenclatura": "0802",
    "etiqueta": "Sin Etiqueta",
    "rack": "145"
}
```

Quisiera renderizar una `DataTable` con los datos de las dos urls para que me despliegue una solo tabla.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({                  
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/switch/?rack='+{{pk3}},
  //////url: '/api/equipos/?rack='+{{pk3}},
        dataSrc: '',
        dataType: 'json',

    },
    columns:[
        {"data":"tipo_equipo"}, /////{"data":"tipo_switch"},
        {"data":"nomenclatura"},
        {"data":"etiqueta"},
        {"data":"rack"},
        {"data":"id"},
   ],

 });

});
```

Me pueden apoyar por favor.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías realizar las dos peticiones ajax por separado, juntar los datos recibidos y aplicárselos al objeto DataTable.

Mira este ejemplo. Primero realiza la petición para los datos de software y con el resultados llama a la función "datosSoftware". Esta función transforma el resultado para reemplazar la propiedad "tipo_sw" por "tipo_equipo" y realiza la petición para recuperar los datos de equipos. Con el resultado de esta petición une los dos conjuntos de datos y los asigna al DataTable:

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  
  // 
  function datosSoftware(softData){
    // cambia la propiedad tipo_sw por tipo_equipo
    var tableData = softData.map(function(data) { 
        return {
          id: data.id, 
          tipo_equipo: data.tipo_sw, 
          nomenclatura: data.nomenclatura, 
          etiqueta: data.etiqueta, 
          rack: data.rack
        });
   // Realiza la petición de datos de equipos y carga el DataTable
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/equipos/?rack=' + {{pk3}},
      dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(equipmentData){
        // Concatena los resultados
        tableData = tableData.concat(equipmentData);
        // Carga el DataTable
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            data: tableData,
            columns: [
              {"data": "tipo_equipo"},
              {"data": "nomenclatura"},
              {"data": "etiqueta"},
              {"data": "rack"},
              {"data": "id"}
          ]});
        });
  }
  
  // Realiza la petición de datos de software y llama a datosSoftware
  $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/switch/?rack=' + {{pk3}},
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(datosSoftware);
  
});
```

Comment: Asier, Muchas gracias por la respuesta, fue de gran ayuda. Saludos!